# Is there a startup option in Mist to specify a blockchain folder?

Tags: blockchain, mist, datadir

I'd like to move my blockchain folder (Windows) from C to E drive. Can I start Mist with an option to use a different folder for blockchain data? If not, can I just make a BAT file with

geth.exe --datadir "E:\Ethereum\data\"
Ethereum-Wallet.exe

and Mist will use that folder?

Why the hell the Mist devs didn't support the same command line option in Mist?